# Elasticsearch search for sum greater than a value

Tags: elasticsearch

Query - find cruises having occupancy.

I need to search for cruises having sum of all (total_occupancy - current_occupancy) of cabins greater than a value (say 100) in ElastcSearch.

PFB a sample cruise document:-

```
{
  "disDmbarkationLocation": "From Location",
  "embarkationLocation": "To Location",
  "segments": [
    {
      "segmentId": "SEG1",
      "cabinInventories": [
        {
          "maxOccupancy": 10,
          "lastModified": 1469538908559,
          "currentOccupancy": 10,
          "cabinNo": 1
        },
        {
          "maxOccupancy": 10,
          "lastModified": 1469538908560,
          "currentOccupancy": 9,
          "cabinNo": 2
        },
        {
          "maxOccupancy": 10,
          "lastModified": 1469538908560,
          "currentOccupancy": 8,
          "cabinNo": 3
        },
        {
          "maxOccupancy": 10,
          "lastModified": 1469538908560,
          "currentOccupancy": 8,
          "cabinNo": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "segmentId": "SEG2",
      "cabinInventories": [
        {
          "maxOccupancy": 10,
          "lastModified": 1469538908561,
          "currentOccupancy": 10,
          "cabinNo": 1
        },
        {
          "maxOccupancy": 10,
          "lastModified": 1469538908562,
          "currentOccupancy": 10,
          "cabinNo": 2
        },
        {
          "maxOccupancy": 10,
          "lastModified": 1469538908562,
          "currentOccupancy": 10,
          "cabinNo": 3
        },
        {
          "maxOccupancy": 10,
          "lastModified": 1469538908562,
          "currentOccupancy": 10,
          "cabinNo": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "segmentId": "SEG3",
      "cabinInventories": [
        {
          "maxOccupancy": 10,
          "lastModified": 1469538908562,
          "currentOccupancy": 10,
          "cabinNo": 1
        },
        {
          "maxOccupancy": 10,
          "lastModified": 1469538908562,
          "currentOccupancy": 8,
          "cabinNo": 2
        },
        {
          "maxOccupancy": 10,
          "lastModified": 1469538908563,
          "currentOccupancy": 8,
          "cabinNo": 3
        },
        {
          "maxOccupancy": 10,
          "lastModified": 1469538908563,
          "currentOccupancy": 8,
          "cabinNo": 4
        }
      ]
    }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample document?

Comment: Please update your question with the same document, it's easier to read than in comments.